# Initializing a class with Class.forName() and which have a constructor with arguments

Tags: scala

I have a class like this:

```
 class NotNullValidationRule(val columns: Set[String],
                            override val acceptanceMin: Double = Constants.DefaultAcceptanceMin)
```

and I'm trying instantiating a class like this.

```
 val param = Set("person_id","participant_id")
 val obj = Class.forName("NotNullValidationRule").getConstructor(Set.getClass).newInstance(param)
```

I was also testing:

```
 val obj = Class.forName("NotNullValidationRule").getConstructor(classOf[String]).newInstance(param)
```

I have not been successful, because this error is throwing me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hammu.rules.validity.NotNullValidationRule.<init>(scala.collection.immutable.Set$)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at com.hammu.run2$.delayedEndpoint$com$bluetab$hammu$run2$1(run2.scala:12)
    at com.hammu.run2$delayedInit$body.apply(run2.scala:7)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.hammu.run2$.main(run2.scala:7)
    at com.hammu.run2.main(run2.scala)
```

help me, please.

Comment: don't think you can ignore the second contstructor argument `val obj = Class.forName(classOf[NotNullValidationRule].getName).getConstructor(classOf[Set[String]], classOf[Double]).newInstance(param, i).asInstanceOf[NotNullValidationRule]`

Comment: Why exactly do you need to instantiate it using **reflection**? Why not just calling the constructor in code? Care to share your real use case, there are probably better options than **reflection**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not have default arguments, that is added magic provided by the Scala compiler.

If you want to use reflection (why, by the way?) you will have to call the method as you would from Java, meaning you have to select the method signature with both arguments (be thankful that there are no multiple parameter groups or implicits!) and also provide values for both.

But again: Reflection is a tool of last resort, especially in Scala. There must surely be a better way to implement your use-case.